# Multiply numbers in Excel or LibreOffice cell contents by a constant when they are mixed with text?

Tags: excel, constants, libreoffice-calc

I have a long series of cells written like this (example text):

```
Example Number (3502, 456)
```

How would I multiply the numbers by 4 without having to delete the text?

I also have cells in the format [sic below]:

```
Example Number (3502,456) (4560,250) (2345,223)
```

et cetera, there are on average ten parentheses per text string.

Occasionally, the text might also be only one word long, e.g.

```
Example (3205, 456)
```

or

```
Example (3205,456) (4560,250) (2345,223)
```

et cetera.

(all above is [sic]).

As a sort of newbie to Excel (well, really Libre Office Calc but it's essentially the same), how would I do this? I don't want to go through and manually multiply all the numbers myself. The number I want to multiply by is 4. I've tried just running a find-and-replace to replace all `,`'s and `)`'s with `*4`'s, but the program I need these numbers for can't evaluate expressions, it needs single numbers.

There are some 110+ items on each list I need to change, and just one math error on any of the three lists (!) and the program won't run correctly (I'm resizing an image, and the points I plotted on the image didn't scale up with it). I don't want to risk it.

Comment: LibreOffice Calc is not the same as Excel, especially as far as macros are concerned - I've suggested edits to your title and tags to reflect this

Answer (score 2):

It should be possible to do this with a macro but unless I'm mistaken LibreOffice macro code is quite different from Excel VBA.

However if you can afford to use several columns of your spreadsheet to figure the values out, you can do so using formulae. If cell A1 contains

```
Example Number (3502,456) (4560,250) (2345,223)
```

and B1 contains

```
=MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,9999)
```

then this formula will return the `3502` as a number:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(B1,FIND(",",B1)-1))
```

(9999 is chosen to be much larger than the likely length of any line, so the `MID` function will always return the whole of the rest of the text after the search character).

You should be able to combine `MID` and `FIND` functions in further cells to isolate the other numbers, assuming these are always found in the format (xxx,yyy) as per your example. Then you can use a final formula to rebuild the string from the multiplied numbers:

```
="Example Number (" & 4*C1 & "," & 4*E1 & ")"
```

and so on.

If your data has a variable number of numbers to find, some of your `FIND` functions may return a `#VALUE` error. You may need to use an `IF` function to exclude these, for example:

```
=IF(ISERROR(G1),"",G1)
```

would return the value of G1 if it contains data, but blank if it contains an error.

Comment: I attempted to implement this solution. However, the trouble is, the =MID(A1,FIND("(",A1)+1,9999) formula successfully extracts the numbers in the ordered pair but keeps the final parenthesis. I implemented this formula

=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,999)

to isolate the second number (don't need up to 9999 because the second number is only 3 digits in each case), but the parenthesis remained. Therefore, the final formula doesn't work correctly. What can be done to get the extra parenthesis out? I'm trying this on my first list, where each number had only one corresponding ordered pair.

Comment: If `B1` is as shown in the answer then in (say) `C1` put `=MID(B1,FIND(","),B1)+1,9999)` to return the rest of the text after the comma, then `=NUMBERVALUE(LEFT(C1,FIND(")",C1)-1))` will return the value of the number before the closing bracket. The `MID` formula is stripping off the part of the string before the search character each time and the `LEFT` formula is accessing the number. Repeat as needed for however many number pairs you have in a row. You may end up with a lot of formulae but it avoids getting involved in macros...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python LibreOffice macro that does what you want.  It assumes all of the values are in column A, and it writes the results to column B.

```py
import re

def do_calculations():
    document = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument() 
    sheet = document.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    cellrange = sheet.getCellRangeByName("A1:A10000")
    row_tuples = cellrange.getDataArray()
    row = 1
    for row_tuple in row_tuples:
        if row_tuple:
            row = output_values(row, row_tuple[0], sheet)

def output_values(row, pairs_string, sheet):
    """Multiply pairs of values by 4 and output each pair to B column.
    :param row: the row number in the B column
    :param pairs_string: a string like "Example Number (123, 456) (789, 1011)"
    :param sheet: the current spreadsheet
    Returns the next row number in the B column.
    """
    pairs = re.findall(r'\([^)]+\)', pairs_string)
    for pair in pairs:
        match_obj = re.match(r'\((\d+),\s*(\d+)\)', pair)
        x, y = match_obj.groups()
        result = "(%d,%d)" % (int(x) * 4, int(y) * 4)
        cell = sheet.getCellRangeByName("B" + str(row))
        cell.setString(result)
        row += 1
    return row

# Functions that can be called from Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro.
g_exportedScripts = do_calculations,
```

Save the code to a text file, for example `calc_multiply_numbers.py`.  Put it in `Scripts/python` in your [LibreOffice user directory](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/UserProfile).  On my Windows system it is `C:\Users\JimStandard\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python`.  If the `python` directory doesn't exist yet, create it.

To run it, open the spreadsheet and go to `Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro`.  Under `My Macros`, click `calc_multiply_numbers` and then press the `Run` button.

**EDIT**:

I don't think you need to worry about the JRE error.  On my system I can uncheck "Use a Java runtime environment" in `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Advanced`, and it still works.  I just click "No" when it asks if I want to enable the use of a JRE now, and then it runs my python macro.

The reason it is not showing up under `My Macros` is because python is not able to interpret the file correctly.  To find the error, test it with python using the following steps (assuming Windows):

1. Open a command prompt, for example by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd>, typing `cmd`, and clicking "Command Prompt" from the start menu.
2. Type cd "*path-to-libreoffice*/program".  On my 64-bit system this is `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program"`  I use the normal Windows File Explorer to find the exact path.
3. Type "python.exe *python-script*".  On my system it is `python.exe "C:\Users\JimStandard\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python\calc_multiply_numbers.py"`

The python interpreter will give an error message about the problem.  If you are not able to figure out the message, write it in the comments below and I will help you.

Comment: I made the .py file, put in the right directory, but Libre says my JRE is defective (I installed a 32-bit JRE v 8u72 just to see if that would help -- my computer is 64-bit), and it won't show up in the Macros list. What could be the problem?

Comment: The solution worked absolutely great. The numbers came out multiplied. Might there be a way to make it output the original words in the same box so I can copy-paste the results into my document even easier? This is still a huge step forward, thanks for the script.

Comment: Since it sounds like this solution answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted.  That way it makes it clear that the question was answered, and it also gives the answerer (me) points, kind of like saying thank you.

Comment: Do you mean to include the "Example Number" text?    To do that, add another line, something like `words_groups = re.search(r'^([^(]+)\(', pairs_string)`.  Then do something like `cell.setString(words_group(1) + result)`.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html.